# Files not getting deleted in android

Tags: android

In my app, i want to delete one sqlite file and one txt file, It doesn't work all the time.

I have given read/writes permissions in android manifest file.

Is it the problem with some specific android version or is there any other way to delete file in java.?

I am using below code.

```
if(file.exists()){
    file.delete()
 }
```

Any idea?

Comment: where does the file exist or the location of the file?

Comment: it is on sd card....i am using String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get the file path..

Comment: File.delete() returns a boolean with the status of the operation.  It looks like you're not checking that to ensure that it actually deletes the File.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the file is still in use and cannot be deleted. You can use FileObserver to check when your file is accessed. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Comment: yes...it can happen...my app uses these files but when i download new sqlite file then old files is not required and i am deleting old file...is there any way i can delete it?

Comment: You can check what happens to your file. See my edited answer.